# Contrast error when using anova to calculated repeated measures

Tags: r, anova

Here is the code I have for calculating repeated measures:

```
aov(avg.active_day ~ date + Error(Turtle/date), data = R3L12.active.day)
```

For this data set, there is a singular turtle that had an activity measurement taken every day for about 10 days. I want to compare if these activity measurements are significantly different from eachother depending on the day. This is basically to see if the turtle exhibits roughly the same movement everyday. But, when I run the ANOVA, I get this error: `` Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels ``

I'm confused because my factor, date, has more than 2 levels...

```
dput(R3L12.active.day)
structure(list(DS = structure(c(1432440000, 1432526400, 1432612800, 
1432699200, 1432785600, 1432872000, 1432958400, 1433044800, 1433131200, 
1433217600, 1433304000, 1433390400), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Turtle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "R3L12", class = "factor"), avg.active_day = c(0, 
15.3846153853846, 44.4444444441667, 25.6410256407692, 16.6666666669231, 
30.555555555, 41.0256410261538, 21.7948717953846, 17.9487179492308, 
0, 0, 2.7777777775), date = structure(c(16579, 16580, 16581, 
16582, 16583, 16584, 16585, 16586, 16587, 16588, 16589, 16590
), class = "Date"), time = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), units = "secs", class = c("hms", "difftime"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `~ date`does not prdouce the error message, `Error(Turtle/date)`does.

Comment: @Pax okay so I'm guessing it's referencing that my Turtle is only 1 level, which it is because I only want to compare the active measurements between that one turtle. How would I go about that then? Thanks!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by the term `Error(Turtle/date)`?

Comment: @Pax, as far as I know, that term is needed to successfully perform a repeated measures calculations. It's showing that Turtle is repeated each day (date).

Comment: True, but `levels(R3L12.active.day$Turtle)` outputs `[1] "R3L12"`. I assume using `aov()` and the specified formula requires more than one turtle. Probably your method is not well-chosen.